# How to access a column in a dataframe when column name is stored in a string in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to access a column in a dataframe, and the column name is stored in a string variable.

I have found this question answered for other languages, and for accesing a variable, but not for a column within a dataframe.

For example:

```
> df <- iris[1:3,]

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

> x <- "Sepal.Length"
```

I want to access the first column of the dataframe df by using x.

I have naively tried the following, without success:

```
df$[[x]]
df$[x]
df$get(x)
```

I imagine it should be straightforward, but I haven't been able to find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From me:

```
df[x]
```

From @[Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas):

Or `df[[x]]`. [MillionC's] returns a sub-data.frame, this one is a vector.

From @[coffeinjunky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2378649/coffeinjunky):

The first two approaches work if you drop the `$`, as @MillionC has pointed out. For subsetting both columns and rows, you can use `df[row_ind, col_ind]`. Your get approach works with `with`, as in `with(df, get(x))`, though I can't think of an example when this construct is needed to subset a dataframe.

Comment: Or `df[[x]]`. Yours returns a sub-data.frame, this one a vector.